# open iOS simulators in OSX

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

How can I open the iOS simulators, that come with the latest XCode, in OSX Mountain Lion?

I can't find the applications in Spotlight search nor in the XCode top-menu-bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the other supporting developer apps are now included inside the Xcode.app bundle.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app
```

Which is also symlinked here:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should check in:

> Preferences > Downloads > Components

Make sure that it is downloaded and installed here.

Then check again, as NReilingh said the directories are:-

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app

symlinked here:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator.app

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, select *Xcode » Open Developer Tool » iOS Simulator* from the menu bar.

Unless you have a launcher like Alfred, Quicksilver, or LaunchBar, this is probably the easiest way to launch any developer tool bundled with Xcode.

<sup>Unlike some other IDEs, Xcode is pretty lightweight and opens quickly if no project is open, so this is a practical solution even if Xcode isn't already running.</sup>